# Go言語の簡易スライス式(s[n:m])について

Tags: go

下記のコードにおいて、(2)はOKで、(3)がruntime errorになるのはどのような理由によるものでしょうか？ Goのバージョンは"go1.11 darwin/amd64"です。

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := "a"
    fmt.Println(a[:len(a)])      // (1) "a"
    fmt.Println(a[len(a):])      // (2) ""
    // fmt.Println(a[len(a)])    // (3) panic - index out of range
    // fmt.Println(a[len(a)+1:]) // (4) panic - slice bounds out of range
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go言語はほとんど使ったことがないんですが、

- 配列のインデックスとしての有効値は`0`から`len(a)-1`まで
- 範囲を指定する場合、(左端)→開始位置のインデックス、(右端)→終了位置のインデックス **+1**で指定する

と言う場合には同じなので。

要素が複数あった方がわかりやすいように思います。

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := "abc"
    fmt.Println(len(a)) //->3
    fmt.Println(a[0]) //->97 ('a')
    fmt.Println(a[1]) //->98 ('b')
    fmt.Println(a[2]) //->99 ('c')
    //fmt.Println(a[3]) //panic: runtime error: index out of range
    fmt.Println(a[0:]) //->abc
    fmt.Println(a[:3]) //->abc
    fmt.Println(a[0:3]) //->abc
    fmt.Println(a[1:]) //->bc
    fmt.Println(a[1:3]) //->bc
    fmt.Println(a[2:]) //->c
    fmt.Println(a[2:3]) //->c
    fmt.Println(a[3:]) //->
    fmt.Println(a[3:3]) //->
    //fmt.Println(a[4:]) //panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
}
```

今の場合`a`(`len(a)==3`)のインデックスはこのように割り振られます。

```
|'a'|'b'|'c'|何もない
 [0] [1] [2] [3]
```

`a[len(a)]`(==`a[3]`)は要素のないところですから当然エラーになります。

だとすると逆に`a[:len(a)]`や`a[len(a):]`はなぜエラーにならないのかですが、上にあげた2番目のルールがあるからです。

`a[:len(a)]`は`len(a)==3`のとき、`a[0:3]`と同じです。

```
|'a'|'b'|'c'|何もない
 [0]←ここから
             [3]←ここの1個前まで
```

`a[3]`には要素は何もないのですが、範囲としてはその1個前までを表すので"abc"を表すことになります。

当然`3`が指定できないと、「最後まで全部」を表す範囲が明示的には書けないことになりますから、範囲の終点としては指定できないと困ります。

また`a[0:3]`が`"abc"`、`a[1:3]`が`"bc"`、そして`a[2:3]`が`"c"`を表すのですから`a[3:3]`が空文字列を表すとするのは極めて自然だと思えないですか? (ま、慣れるまでは思えないかもしれませんが…。)

と言うわけで(人間にとってと言うより機械の都合にとってと言う感じですが)`3`は範囲の始点を表す時、(必ず終点も同じでないといけませんが)有効な値ということになります。

```
a[0:]
|'a'|'b'|'c'|何もない
 [0]←ここから全部(`"abc"`)

a[3:]
|'a'|'b'|'c'|何もない
             [3]←ここから全部(`""`)
```

あなたのあげた例の場合は`len(a)==1`なのでかえってピンとこないかもしれませんがほとんど同じことです。

```
a[:0] (==a[:len(a)]
|'a'|何もない
     [1]←この1個前まで全部("a")
```

```
a[0:] (==a[len(a):]
|'a'|何もない
     [1]←ここから全部("")
```

---

なんでこんなわかりにくい範囲指定をするのかは、その方が色々便利だから、ですが、その辺はこのやり方で経験を積まれれば、自然に見えてくるかと思います。

それ他の点で何か分かりにくい点があれば、お知らせください。

Comment: 丁寧な回答をありがとうございます。範囲指定の際の終了位置については理解しているつもりでしたが、開始位置は有効な要素を保持している位置でなければならないと思っていました。スライスの範囲の指定の説明として、[n,m)が

Comment: 途中で回答してしまいました。失礼しました。ご丁寧な回答をありがとうございます。助かりました。範囲指定の際の終了位置(a[n,m)のm)については理解しているつもりでしたが、開始位置は有効な要素を保持している位置でなければならないと思っていました。「何もないところから全部」をもう一度見直してゆっくり考えます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。半開区間の「開始位置は有効な要素を保持している位置でなければならない」という感覚は至極もっともだと思います。すでにご理解されていることを長々と説明したわりに、肝心なところを「その方が色々便利だから」で誤魔化してしまってますんで、またお気付きの点お知らせ頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 0):

回答ではありませんが、ソースコード上での処理はどの様になっているのか調べてみました。

スライスの処理は[ここ](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/ssa.go#4359)で行われています。

> slice computes the slice v[i:j:k] and returns ptr, len, and cap of result. **i,j,k may be nil, in which case they are set to their default value**.

コメントにあるように、`a[len(a):]` の場合は `a[len(a):len(a)]` として扱われて、境界チェック(bounds checking)が行われます。この場合、`a` は文字列ですので、最終的に `s.boundsCheck(i, j, ssa.BoundsSliceB, bounded)` が実行されることになります。

```golang
case t.IsString():
  ptr = s.newValue1(ssa.OpStringPtr, types.NewPtr(types.Types[TUINT8]), v)
  len = s.newValue1(ssa.OpStringLen, types.Types[TINT], v)
  cap = len
      :

// Set default values
      :
if j == nil {
  j = len
}
three := true
if k == nil {
  three = false
  k = cap
}

// Panic if slice indices are not in bounds.
      :
if three {
      :        
} else {
  if j != k {
      :        
  }
  i = s.boundsCheck(i, j, ssa.BoundsSliceB, bounded)
}
```

`ssa.BoundsSliceB` は境界チェック用のオペレーション・コードですが、[ここ](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/ssa/op.go#190)で定義されています。

```golang
type BoundsKind uint8

const (
  BoundsIndex    BoundsKind = iota // indexing operation, 0 <= idx < len failed
               :
  BoundsSliceB     // 2-arg slicing operation, 0 <= low <= high failed
```

判定条件は `0 <= low <= high` となっていて、`low`, `high` ともに `len(a)` であるため境界内であると判定されることになります。

`a[len(a)+1:]` の場合は `low = len(a)+1`, `high = len(a)` となるので、`low > high` となってしまい、境界チェックに引っ掛かってしまいます(`panic(bounds out of range)`が発生)。

仮に判定条件が `0 <= low < high` となっていたとすれば `a[len(a):]` でも panic が発生することになったはずです。

ちなみに、`a[len(a)]` の様なインデックスによるアクセスの場合には `BoundsIndex` でチェックされますので、先に引用したコードにもある通り、`0 <= idx < len` が判定条件になります(`a[len(a)]` では `index out of range` となる)。